# "set listchars=tab:>-,eol:$,space:·" the "space:·" part doesn't work?

Tags: vim

So strange is that it's all right before, but after I added one line in the vimrc with Windows Notepad, the error occur! And it makes me crazy!

Here is ":set listchars" part of my vimrc:

```
set listchars=tab:>-,eol:$,space:·
```

encountering error:

```
E474: invalid argument: listchars=tab:>-,eol:$,space:<a1><a4>
```

[image: Screenshot]
[image: vimrc]

Comment: Maybe character set problem. What happens, when you add `scriptencoding utf-8` as the first entry in your `vimrc`? Are you setting `encoding` in your `vimrc`?

Comment: Yes, added scriptencoding utf-8, doesn't work! Below is my vimrc beginning: set fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,cp936,gb18030,big5,euc-jp,sjis,euc-kr,ucs-2le,latin1
"On gvim, must set encoding=utf-8 at the top or Alt mappings defined thereafter will not work.
set encoding=utf-8 
set termencoding=utf-8 
set fileencoding=utf-8 
set listchars=tab:>-,eol:$,space:·

Comment: What encoding is your vimrc in? `<a1><a4>` is not UTF-8.

Comment: utf-8 and I have updated the post to give more info.

Comment: How do you know it's in UTF-8?

Comment: Check fileencoding with `set fileencoding?`. Make sure it is utf-8. Then move `scriptencoding utf-8` below `set encoding=utf-8`.

Comment: You can also try to work around the vimrc encoding issues via: `let &listchars = "tab:>-,eol:$,space:\u00B7"`

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it's utf-8. And I put scriptencoding utf-8 below set encoding=utf-8 like you said, it work! Thanks! But could you tell me why?

Answer (score 2):

As you're using non-ASCII characters, you need to use [`:help :scriptencoding`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#%3Ascriptencoding) to specify the encoding of your `~/.vimrc`.

You're also overriding the default `'encoding'`, which affects the representation of any text inside Vim, also any non-ASCII text already read in. Therefore, you first need to `:set encoding`, and only then (with the correct internal representation set) can you specify the script's encoding:

```
set encoding=utf-8
scriptencoding utf-8
set listchars=...
```

Alternatively, you could also work around the vimrc encoding issues by encoding the non-ASCII characters in a (double-quoted) string ([`:help expr-quote`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#expr-quote)), and using `:let &option` instead of `:set`:

```
let &listchars = "tab:>-,eol:$,space:\u00B7"
```

Comment: Thanks! You said "You're also overriding the default `'encoding'`", what is overriding the default?scriptencoding?

Comment: `:set encoding=...` is overriding Vim's default (`latin1`, or based on `$LANG`, though that's usually not set on Windows).

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that Vim is loading the file `vimrc` with some encoding that is not UTF-8. I don't know which encoding is used.

To force Vim to interpret `vimrc` as UTF-8, the following line is needed:

```
scriptencoding utf-8
```

All lines following this lines are then interpreted as UTF-8. All lines before that line are interpreted in whatever Vim determines.

If you set `encoding` in your `vimrc`, the line `scriptencoding` must be after that line.

So in your case, you need:

```
set encoding=utf-8
scriptencoding utf-8
```

See `:help :scriptencoding` for details.